# AsyncStorage returns unexpected error

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-native, asyncstorage

Please forgive me if this question is caused by syntax error or of the sort, I'm new to React-Native and there is still many to learn.

I followed the docs and tried out AsyncStorage but it returns an error.

```
class iCare extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);

async getUserStatus(key){
  try{
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value == null || value == 0){
      console.log('No loggedIn key yet.');
      loggedIn: false;
    } else {
      console.log('loggedIn key existed');
      loggedIn: true;
    }
  }catch(error){
    console.log('caught error' + error);
  }
}
}
```

The error says something is wrong with **AsyncStorage**, but why?
[image: Screenshot]

Just for the knowledge, is it wise to do AsyncOperation in a constructor method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is late, but try this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

async getUserStatus(key){
  try{
    var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value == null || value == 0){
      console.log('No loggedIn key yet.');
      loggedIn = false;
    } else {
      console.log('loggedIn key existed');
      loggedIn = true;
    }
  }catch(error){
    console.log('caught error' + error);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's really helpful! I finally found out my mistakes! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are use object notation, instead of an assignment here:

```
     loggedIn: false;
```

Should be:

```
//define logged in somewhere before let loggedIn = null;
loggedIn = true;
```

or:

```
//return an actual object?
return {loggedIn: false};
```

You also need to import AsyncStorage

```
var { AsyncStorage } = React;
```

Comment: I changed, the problem still persists, looks like the program hasn't even got passed the code `var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);`

Comment: You probably need to import AsyncStorage, doubt it's a global.

Comment: I have included this globally... 'var {
  Alert,
  AppRegistry,
  AsyncStorage,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  Component,
} = React;'